# Why would a read from process memory fail when the app is not run from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, windows, memory, operating-system

I found code for a mono injector, but it somehow won't work when not run from Visual studio. it fails at the following code(throws exception):

```
public byte[] ReadBytes(IntPtr address, int size)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];

    if (!Native.ReadProcessMemory(_handle, address, bytes, size))
        throw new InjectorException("Failed to read process memory", new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));

    return bytes;
}
```

Where `ReadProcessMemory(...)`
is declared as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, int nSize, int lpNumberOfBytesRead = 0);
```

Does Visual Studio has more privileges which allows it to read memory from other processes compared to a plain binary?

Here is the SharpMonoInjector2.2 repo:
`https://github.com/warbler/SharpMonoInjector`

Comment: Last parameter is not int

Comment: @Anders, sorry, I dont understand.